# Apache RewriteRule pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I writing an .htaccess file for the web resources management.

I would like to this pattern of URI to use for static resource

```
^.*/web-console/static/(.*)$
```

And, my RewriteRule is below.

```
RewriteRule "^.*/web-console/static/(.*)$" "resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/$1" [L]
```

And, I request below URI

```
http://myhost/shop/web-console/static/css/default.css
```

But the Apache server hasn't match URI.
And if I delete "/web-console" Apache works fine.
Below is the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule "^.*/static/(.*)$" "resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/$1" [L]
```

What is a problem?

## Appendix

this is my directory structure

web base - /data/web
site base - /data/web/shop
htaccess - /data/web/shop/.htaccess
router script - /data/web/shop/route.php
static resources - /data/web/shop/resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static
css file - /data/web/shop/resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/css/default.css

So, I wish response static resources if URI is started /shop/web-console/static
And, other case is pass to router script using "RewriteRule .* route.php [L]"

Comment: so web-console is not a real directory?

Comment: Yes, that is not a real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself.

```
RewriteRule "web-console/static/(.*)$" "resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/$1" [END]
```

I'd change that flag from `L` to `END`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this. If you have this .htaccess in a sub folder `shop`, you should add rewritebase.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^web-console/static/(.*)$" "resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/$1" [L]
```

Comment: I need more explanation than not working or I can't help you troubleshoot. What isn't working? Any errors? where is the .htaccess file located? where is your resources directory, in the root or under shop?

Comment: Oh, sorry for my description. I mean that rewriterule does not catch up URI. If that work show my default.css file contents, but it's did not catch and work as below this statement "RewriteRule .* route.php [L]".

Comment: And my .htaccess file is located in /data/web/shop folder

Comment: And my default.css file is located /data/web/shop/resources/floworks-web-console-1.0/static/css/default.css

Comment: which folder is considered your doc root apache? web or shop? meaning is the URL www.example.com/shop?

Comment: apache web root is /data/web and you right URL is like that